# Using Scala method in Java

Tags: java, scala, gradle, javafx, groovy

I tries use Scala method from Java. But still has error. I use JavaFX JetBrains Intellij IDEA gradle groovy sample project
"ls" result:
Chat.java  HelloApplication.java  HelloController.java  MessengerAPI.scala
Error:

```
/home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Scala/Messenger/src/main/java/com/sanorian/messenger/HelloController.java:58: error: package MessengerAPI$ does not exist
        MessengerAPI$.MODULE$.sendMessage(message);
                     ^
```

I changes gradle.build file for compiling scala files too. But it still crashing

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.sanorian'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.0'
    scalaVersion = '2.13.6'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ['-target:jvm-17']
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.sanorian.messenger'
    mainClass = 'com.sanorian.messenger.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.6'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${scalaVersion}"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Main code:

```
    @FXML
    protected void sendMessage() {
        String message = textarea.getText();
        textarea.setText("");
        MessengerAPI$.MODULE$.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

Scala code:

```
package com.sanorian.messenger

object MessengerAPI {
  def sendMessage(message: String): Unit = {
    println(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you just missing an `import com.sanorian.messenger.MessengerAPI$`?